# Is there any solution to redirect facebook fan page after submission

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

In my facebook App, I just pull my website form to enter the data. After submit the form it's showing Successfully Message. Now I want to re-direct it to my Facebok fan page. But I can't. I used several method but I'm going to crazy :(

```
<?php
echo "<div class='success'><font color='green' size='5'>Congratulation!. Successfully submited your recipe. Thank You.</font/></center></div>";
//header("Refresh:5; url=fan_page_url");
//echo "top.location.href='fan_page_url'";
//header("Refresh: 1;");
//header("Location: fan_page_url");
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.location.href = 'fan_page_url';
</script>
```

Comment: You may need to provide the complete url http://domain.com/fapageurl

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I used http://www.myfbfanpage.com, http://www.facebook.com. but bad luck.

Comment: so the submit is happening on your FB canvas page ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes.

Comment: Added an answer try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/fanapage';
 </script>
```

Comment: the app is inside the iframe so the the usual redirect wount work. Let me try something on my test app

Comment: Ok..Abhik Chakraborty.

Comment: your app type is iframe ?

Comment: No It's not iframe. It's Facebook Developer App.

Comment: just try window.top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/fanapage'; as updated in the answer

Comment: AH !! this should have worked I am running out all of solutions !

Comment: last thing why dont u add the js code in PHP echo '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
    window.top.location = \'http://www.facebook.com/fanapage\';
 </script>' ;
exit;

Comment: One last question: How do redirect a page after 5 seconds with this code "<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/fanapage';
 </script>" ?

Comment: You can use setInterval() function https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Answer (score 0):

This is working if I simply run it into localhost, try it.

```
<?php
echo "<div class='success'><font color='green' size='5'>Congratulation!. Successfully submited your recipe. Thank You.</font/></center></div>";
//header("Refresh:5; url=fan_page_url");
//echo "top.location.href='fan_page_url'";
//header("Refresh: 1;");
//header("Location: fan_page_url");
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/jQuery";
</script>
```

Comment: what's your path for facebook page?

Comment: ...https://apps.facebook.com/bdrecipe/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0

Comment: can you confirm that the code between the script tag is running?

Comment: How do i confirm it ? I just used this script tag code to my success message div.

Comment: give `alert('something');` statement before `window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/jQuery";`